# Hiding specific form inputs when radio buttons are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

My second radio button works as intended. I'm trying to get my first radio button (Business name) to hide the second input field when selected.

```js
function formChoice(x)
{
  if(x==0)
    $('#field1').css('display', 'block');
  else
    $('#field1').css('display', 'none');
  return;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
<h1> Trying to hide second input field when 'Business URL' is selected</h1>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
  <input type="radio" name="rad1" onclick="formChoice(0)" checked> Business URL
    <input type="text" name="businessSite" id="field1">
  <input type="radio" name="rad1" onclick="formChoice(1)"> I don't have a website but here are some sites I like!
    <input type="text" name="businessSite" id="field2">
  </form>
```

Comment: This appears to be working. You need to include Jquery or javascript reference i think.

Answer (score 0):

Here I made a few edits so you can see which input is which, then also I hide "input 2" when business URL radio is checked.

```js
function formChoice(x)
{
  if(x==0)
    $('#field2').css('display', 'none');
  else
    $('#field2').css('display', 'block');
  return;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
<h1> Trying to hide second input field when 'Business URL' is selected</h1>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
  <input type="radio" name="rad1" onclick="formChoice(0)"> Business URL
    <input type="text" name="businessSite" id="field1" value ="input1">
  <input type="radio" name="rad1" onclick="formChoice(1)"> I don't have a website but here are some sites I like!
    <input type="text" name="businessSite" id="field2" value="input2">
  </form>
```

Comment: Hmm  I still see the first input field when I have the second radio button selected with this one.

Comment: This worked after adding brackets around the 'else'.

Comment: Glad I could help @Cosmos. If this answered your question, please mark as answer. thanks and best of luck in your app building!

Answer (score 0):

```
function formChoice(x)
{
  if(x==0) {
    $('#field1').css('display', 'block');
    $('#field2').css('display', 'none');
  } else {
    $('#field1').css('display', 'none');
    $('#field2').css('display', 'block');
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: I'm still seeing the first input field with the second radio button selected. Any way around that?

Comment: Try adding curly brackets for the if an else.  I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please check if your jQuery import is correct.

You might want to update both fields together.

```
function formChoice(x) { 
    if(x==0){
      $('#field1').show();
      $('#field2').hide();
    } else {
      $('#field1').hide();
      $('#field2').show();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost executing the right logic.

## Your approach

```
function formChoice(x) {
  if(x==0)
    $('#field1').css('display', 'block');
  else
    $('#field1').css('display', 'none');
}
```

When your radiobutton `field1` is selected your trying to hide using `$('#field1').css('display', 'block');`.  What you want to do is set `display: none`

```
$('#field1').css('display', 'block');
                             ^
```

You radiobutton `field1` is already checked, probably you don't want  that:

```
<input type="radio" name="rad1" onclick="formChoice(0)" checked>
                                                        ^
```

## Look this code snippet with those fixes

```js
function formChoice(x) {
  if (x == 0)
    $('#field2').css('display', 'none');
  else
    $('#field2').css('display', 'block');
  return;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> Trying to hide second input field when 'Business URL' is selected</h1>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="rad1" onclick="formChoice(0)"> Business URL<br>
  <input type="text" name="businessSite" id="field1"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="rad1" onclick="formChoice(1)"> I don't have a website but here are some sites I like!<br>
  <input type="text" name="businessSite" id="field2">
</form>
```

See? now your logic is working well :-)

Comment: I'm still seeing the first input field with the second radio button selected. Any way around that?

Comment: @Cosmos your question doesn't state  that.

Comment: This worked after adding brackets around the 'else' and removing 'return'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix `formChoice` like this to make it respond to the parameter:

```
function formChoice(x)
{
    $('#field' + x).css('display', 'block');
}
```

and pass the correct value when you call it into the html:

```
<head>
<h1> Trying to hide second input field when 'Business URL' is selected</h1>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
  <input type="radio" name="rad1" onclick="formChoice(2)" checked> Business URL
    <input type="text" name="businessSite" id="field1">
  <input type="radio" name="rad1" onclick="formChoice(1)"> I don't have a website but here are some sites I like!
    <input type="text" name="businessSite" id="field2">
  </form>
```